# If $A,B,A+I,A+B$ are idempotent matrices how to show that $AB=BA$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, idempotents

> If $A,B,A+I,A+B$ are idempotent matrices how to show that $AB=BA$ ?

**MY ATTEMPT:**

$A\cdot A=A$

$B\cdot B=B$

$(A+I)\cdot (A+I)=A+I$ or, $A\cdot A+A\cdot I+I\cdot A+I\cdot I=A+I$ which implies $A\cdot I+I\cdot A=0$ (using above equations)

$(A+B)\cdot (A+B)=A+B$ or,$A\cdot A+A\cdot B+B\cdot A+B\cdot B=A+B$ which implies $A\cdot B+B\cdot A=0$

What's next?

Comment: Your first equation says $A=-A$ your second says $AB=B(-A)$ but substituting your first equation gives $AB=BA$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, $AI=IA=A$, so your equation $AI+IA=0$ actually says $2A=0$.  Over a field of characteristic $\neq 2$, this implies $A=0$, so $AB=BA=0$ trivially.  Over a field of characteristic $2$, your equation $AB+BA=0$ gives $AB=-BA$, and $-BA=BA$ since the characteristic is $2$.

(Incidentally, if $A$, $B$, and $A+B$ are all idempotent this already implies that $AB=BA$, and that $AB=BA=0$ if the characteristic is not $2$.  As you derived, you get $AB+BA=0$ and hence $AB=-BA$.  But then $$AB=(A^2)B=A(AB)=-A(BA)=-(AB)A=(BA)A=B(A^2)=BA.$$  If the characteristic is not $2$, $AB=BA=-BA$ implies $AB=BA=0$.)

Comment: @Eric Wofsey please can you explain it a bit further im not correctly getting you

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: What part in particular do you not understand?

Comment: The second para

Answer (score 4):

Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of a (possibly noncommutative) ring. If $a$, $b$, $a+1$ and $a+b$ are idempotent, then $ab = ba$.

**Proof**. From $a^2 = a$ and $(a+1)^2 = a+ 1$ one gets $a^2 + a + a + 1 = a + 1$, whence $a^2 + a = 0$. Since $a^2 = a$, it follows that $a + a = 0$ and finally $a = -a$. Now, from $(a+b)^2 = a + b$ one gets $a^2 + ab + ba + b^2 = a + b$. Again, since $a^2 = a$ and $b^2 = b$, it follows $ab + ba = 0$, and since $a = -a$, we finally get $ab -ab= 0$, that is $ab = ba$.