# If $A$, $B$ idempotent and $AB=0$, then $A+B$ idempotent.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, idempotents

We know that if $A,B$ idempotent then we have (see edit) $$(A+B)^2=A+B\implies AB=0,$$
and I'm wondering whether the converse, i.e. that if $A,B$ idempotent and $AB=0$ then $A+B$ idempotent is true. Expanding we get
$$(A+B)^2=A^2+AB+BA+B^2=A+B+BA$$
so we just need to show that $BA=0$. It certainly isn't true in general that $AB=0\implies BA=0$, but I couldn't think of an example where $A$ and $B$ are idempotent. For orthogonal projections at least I think that the statement is true (by thinking geometrically), but I need to consider general projections.

My intuition is that this statement probably is true. Is this correct, and if so how can I show this?

Edit:
$(A+B)^2=A+B\implies AB=-BA$, but then $BAB=-BA$ and $AB=-BAB$, so $AB=BA$ and therefore $AB=BA=0$.

Comment: $\det AB = \det A \cdot \det B = \det B \cdot \det A = \det BA$ since the matrices are square and conformable.  $\det A^2 = \det A = \det A\cdot \det A$ so $\det A = 0$ or $1$. Does that help?

Comment: Why do we know that $(A+B)^2=A+B$ implies that $AB=0$? In fact, as you show, only $AB+BA=0$ follows.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor An invertible idempotent must be the identity: $A = AAA^{-1} = AA^{-1} = I$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde A proof is given as an aside in the accepted answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605229/if-a-b-ai-ab-are-idempotent-matrices-how-to-show-that-ab-ba

Comment: @DietrichBurde I'll edit the question to be more clear here. It isn't an obvious consequence but as saulspatz's link shows, it does follow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What if $A =\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$ and $B =\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)$?

$AB = 0$, but $BA = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)$.

And $A+B = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)$ is not idempotent since $(A+B)^2 = \left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 2 & 1 \end{matrix}\right)$.

Answer (score 6):

**Counterexample:**  Let
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \qquad B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
Both matrices are idempotent.  Then $AB = 0$ but $BA \neq 0$.

Thinking about this in terms of general projections:  $A$ projects a vector along a horizontal line to the line $x = -y$, while $B$ projects along a vertical line to the line $y = 0$ (the $x$-axis).  Applying $B$ and then $A$ always yields the zero vector, since $Bv$ always yields a vector with no $y$-component.  But applying $A$ and then $B$ does not necessarily yield the zero vector, since $Av$ will usually have a non-zero $x$-component.